# Finding $341a - a^5$ when $a^2 + 2a - 13 = 0$

Tags: roots

Suppose $a$ is a root of $x^2 + 2x - 13.$ Than, find the value of $341a - a^5.$

---

I was thinking of trying to find a substitution to find the value of $341a - a^5,$ but I'm not sure what. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Well...$a^2=13-2a\implies a^3=13a-2a^2=13a-2(13-2a)=13a-26+4a=17a-26$ and so on.

Comment: and in this case it reduces beautifully

Comment: $780\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: "and in this case it reduces beautifully"  I dunno, I tried it 5 times and got 6 different results.... then again arithmetic errors are par for the course.

Comment: How to avoid arithmetic errors: (21:54) gp > a=Mod(y,y^2+2*y-13);
(21:54) gp > lift(341*a-a^5)
%55 = 780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$  \left(   -  x^{5}  + 341 x  \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  - 13 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   -  x^{3}  + 2 x^{2}  - 17 x  + 60 \right) } +  \left( 780  \right)  $$

...............

Answer (score 0):

First divide $341a - a^5$ by $a^2+2a-13$ to get a remainder of $ja + k$.  Then plug in $a = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4+4*13}}{2}=-1\pm \sqrt{1+13}$.

$-a^5 +341a = -a^3(a^2 + 2a-13) + 2a^4-13a^3 +341a=$

$2a^4 - 13a^3 + 341a= 2a^2(a^2+2a-13) -4a^3+26a^2 -13a^3+341a=$

$-17a^3 + 26a^2 + 341a = -17a(a^2 + 2a -13) +34a^2-17*13a +26a^2 + 341a =$

$60a^2 + 120a = 60(a^2 +2a -13) -120a + 60*13 +120a = $

$780$.

And ... we don't need to plug is $a =-1\pm\sqrt {14}$.

.....

Of course the *real* hard part is not to make any effing arithmetic errors!